# Restore closing slash in br tag in TinyMCE?

Tags: html, tinymce

I'm trying to upgrade from an old TinyMCE 4.9 installation to the current version 6.3. It looks like somewhere between those versions, TinyMCE started writing line break tags as `<br>` instead of `<br />`. But I have 12 years of user data that uses `<br />` and a large, multi-platform system that relies on that format for parsing. Is there a way to revert to the previous format?

A common answer to questions like this is to do my own post-processing to change any TinyMCE formatting I don't like, but one reason I'm upgrading is to reduce the number of hacks like this that I'm already using. This one would be especially confusing because `<br>` would be used in several editing functions on the web platform while `<br />` is used everywhere else.

This seems like it would be a breaking change for a lot of users, so I'd be surprised if there isn't some built-in way to adjust it. But I've searched the web, the TinyMCE docs and the source code with no luck. I can't even find a mention of it being changed in the change log.

I did find references to a `closed` configuration option that might be what I want, but only in 8+ year old posts, and this option no longer appears in the documentation. I took a guess and tried adding `closed : "br"` to my configuration, but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, while searching the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues) I found a solution! The [element_format](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-filtering/#element_format) configuration option with a value of "xhtml" restores the previous formatting of singleton tags:

`element_format: 'xhtml'`

The change log shows that the default value for this option was changed to "html" in TinyMCE 6.0.